# onClick() event confusion with parameter

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a view that has an `onClick` property:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hey"
    android:onClick="showCity" />
```

Which corresponds to this method:

```
public void showCity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CityActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

However, I have a menu item that I want to have open the `CityActivity` as well:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_city:
            showCity();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work because it's missing the `view` parameter in the call to `showCity()` and I'm not sure what it should be in this case.

How do I modify it to work in both cases?

Comment: In `showCity()` method you never use `view` parameter ! remove it if you dont need it else pass null as view and check it for null in your method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your `onOptionsItemSelected` code with following following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_city:
            showCity(null);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

You `showCity` must have the `View` parameter instead of that you can pass `null` as parameter to your `onClick()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't use the `view` parameter, you can just pass `null` to it and it will work

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass `null` i.e. `showCity(null)`

Answer (score 0):

Write an id attribute to your textview in xml as shown below, you can also remove the onClick attribute of the TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tShowCity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hey"
    />
```

Now in your onCreate() method of the activity initize your TextView as shown below and write the click listener for the TextView as shown below:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tShowCity);

tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     showCity();
                }
            });
```

now define your show city method as shown below:

```
public void showCity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CityActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now the above method can also be used in your Menu and will function without any issue as:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_city:
            showCity();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `View` property ..as answer already you can pass `null` value to your showCity()

```
showCity(null);
```

But if you want to use specific view properties in your `showCity()` you can pass view a with id by `findViewById()` method..like.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        showCity(this.findViewById(R.id.textview1));
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are not using view , so why are you add in your Method Parameter...
    public void showCity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CityActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

Look...

```
public void showCity() {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CityActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Simple..... :)